# render function or template not defined in component: Swiper

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, render, swiper.js

I am using `swiper` in `nuxt.js`. I tried the example from their documentation, but I get an error:

```html
<template>
  <swiper
    :slides-per-view="3"
    :space-between="50"
    navigation
    :pagination="{ clickable: true }"
    :scrollbar="{ draggable: true }"
    @swiper="onSwiper"
    @slideChange="onSlideChange"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    ...
  </swiper>
</template>
<script>
// import Swiper core and required components
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';

// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';

// install Swiper components
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

// Import Swiper styles
export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  methods: {
    onSwiper(swiper) {
      console.log(swiper)
    },
    onSlideChange() {
      console.log('slide change')
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**error in browser**
[image]

**warnings in console in terminal console**
[image]

**my package.json**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Swiper docs](https://swiperjs.com/vue/) state:

> Swiper Vue.js components are compatible only with new Vue.js version 3.

Nuxt 2.x currently uses Vue 2, which causes the error you mentioned. A workaround is to use Swiper's API with HTML, as shown in the component below:

```html
<template>
  <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          ...
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

      <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'

Swiper.use([ Navigation, Pagination ])

export default {
  mounted() {
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
      },
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.swiper-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the container in `<client-only></client-only>` if you are using newer version of nuxtjs. Use `<no-ssr></no-ssr>` for older versions

Comment: i am using ssr, can't it affect my app

Comment: i did it but it is not being displayed. i found that `swipper vue` is only supported in `vue 3`