# render function or template not defined in component - Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I installed the package `vue-awesome-swiper` to create a carousel, but when declaring my component and accessing the page it throws the message `render function or template not defined in component`

Carousel

```html
<template>
  <swiper ref="mySwiper" :options="options">
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "vue-awesome-swiper";

export default {
  name: "carousel",
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide
  },
  data() {
    return {
      swiperOptions: {
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination"
        }
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.mySwiper.$swiper;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Current Swiper instance object", this.swiper);
    this.swiper.slideTo(3, 1000, false);
  }
};
</script>
```

Already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260924/render-function-or-template-not-defined-in-component-swiper). It throws me the same message.

Or any ideas on which package I can use to implement a carousel?

EDIT: Solution I tried:

```js
<template>
  <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          ...
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

      <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
      <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper'
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'

Swiper.use([ Navigation, Pagination ])

export default {
  mounted() {
    new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      loop: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
      },
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code with the other solution? Also, why version of the package do you use?

Comment: I have updated the question